# PHP: print from a list of data (loop difficult)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Hi i have a little problem,my code create a list of buttons and each button have a name(value) from my list (table 'usernames')
....for exemple (table 'usernames' have 3 lines aa-bb-cc my code make 3 button with values aa & bb & cc..............
so what i want to do, is when i click on a button i want to print the value of this button in a div, for exemple if i click on the button who have the value 2 i want to print 2 in the div(i have a problem whit my loop, and i need help please)

this is my code:

```html
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pwd","sn") or die(mysqli_error());
    $que2=mysqli_query($conn,"select usernames from posts", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT); // return a lot of lines on 'usernames'
    $re=0;
    $datax=array();
    $i=0;
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($que2))
    {
       $re = $r["cnt"];
       $datax[$i]=$re;
        ?>
        <input id="ppost" name="ppost" value="<?php echo $datax[$i]; ?>" type="submit">
        <br>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
       $('#ppost').click(function(){
        alert("<?php echo $datax[$i]; ?>");
       });
       });
     </script>
       <?php
       $i++;
   }
```

Comment: can you specify your question - what's the problem: the loop doesn't generate what you expect or you don't know how to print the username in the div? Also can you post full code - I can't see neither the `<div>` to print in nor the `<form>` elements ...

Comment: i dont know how to print the specify name of the button who i clicked on, my code show me all buttons name when i click on it and i don't want this. i want when i click on a button i see his name.

Comment: ok what have you tried already?

Comment: read my syntax please, ... my code print on an alert message all the names of buttons, i want to print just the name of the button who i clicked on not all buttons

Comment: You look like you are just printing the full array hence all print. You do not need to echo like that. Just access the button Value with jquery. So you create your button with php and the values etc then instead of echoing button do an on click - access this buttons attributes of choice with jquery and .html it wherever you want.

Comment: Access like this:                $('.my_button').click(function() {
            alert($(this).val());    Where .my_button is your button class. Give them all same class. Obviously this is alerting you just need to put into div

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so there're few things to have a look at:

1. take  the `<script>` out of the loop - one script can take care of all the buttons
2. you can't give same ID to all your inputs - `id="..."` has to be unique throughout your script
3. the JS script (assuming you have jQuery included prior to your ) should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
   $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('value'));
   });
   });
</script>
```

this should do the trick, let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: yes :D thats what i want :) thnx a lot bro :) my problem is down now :)

Comment: glad to help! btw if this is the solution to your problem, please accept the answer to close the question. cheers!